# Laravel Retrieve Images from storage to view

Tags: laravel

I am using below code to store the uploaded file

```
 $file = $request->file($file_attachment);
        $rules = [];
        $rules[$file_attachment] = 'required|mimes:jpeg|max:500';
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->with('uploadErrors', $validator->errors());
        }

        $userid = session()->get('user')->id;
        $destinationPath = config('app.filesDestinationPath') . '/' . $userid . '/';
        $uploaded = Storage::put($destinationPath . $file_attachment . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension(), file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
```

The uploaded files are stored in **storage/app/2/filename.jpg**

I want to show back the user the file he uploaded. How can i do that?

$storage = Storage::get('/2/filename.jpg');

I am getting unreadable texts. I can confirm that the file is read. But how to show it as an image to the user.

Hope i made my point clear.

**Working Solution**

display.blade.php

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/photo.jpg') }}" />
```

web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('storage/{filename}', function ($filename) {
        $userid = session()->get('user')->id;
        return Storage::get($userid . '/' . $filename);
    });
});
```

Thanks to: @Boghani Chirag and @rkj

Comment: have you tried creating symlink to your image storage folder from public folder? Then access the url from there? (some nginx/apache config might needed to allow symlinked dir) And while I am not recommend this, tried to save it on public folder. Personally, I prefer upload the image after processing it to some cdn or image provider like cloudinary and serve the url from them.

Comment: No. I cant do that. The user information is more sensitive and i cant put it in public folder or cloudinary...

Comment: I see, what about serve it as data-uris? Serve over to the user using img tag: https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/

Comment: you can store filename in db and then you can easily find path to show in blade file

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> File not publicly accessible like you said then read file like this

```
$userid = session()->get('user')->id;
$contents = Storage::get($userid.'/file.jpg');
```

Assuming your file is at path `storage/app/{$userid}/file.jpg`
    and default disk is `local` check `config/filesystems.php`

> File publicly accessible

If you want to make your file publicly accessible then store file inside this `storage/app/public` folder. You can create subfolders inside it and upload there. Once you store file inside  `storage/app/public` then you have to just create a symbolic link and laravel has artisan command for it.

```
php artisan storage:link
```

This create a symbolic link of `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`. Means now you can access your file like this

```
$contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('file.jpg');
```

here the file physical path is at `storage/app/public/file.jpg` and it access through symbolic link path `public/storage/file.jpg`

**Suppose you have subfolder** `storage/app/public/uploads` where you store your uploaded files then you can access it like this

```
$contents = Storage::disk('public')->get('uploads/file.jpg');
```

> When you make your upload in public folder then you can access it in view

```
echo asset('storage/file.jpg'); //without subfolder uploads

echo asset('storage/uploads/file.jpg');
```

check for details https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#configuration

Answer (score 7):

[image]

**Remember put your folder in storage/app/public/**

Create the symbolic linksymbolic link to access this folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

if you want to access profile images of 2 folder then do like this in your blade file

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/2/images/'.$user->profile_image) }}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel 8

Controller

```
class MediaController extends Controller
{ 

    public function show(Request $request, $filename)
    {
        $folder_name = 'upload';

        $filename = 'example_img.jpeg';

        $path = $folder_name.'/'.$filename;

        if(!Storage::exists($path)){
            abort(404);
        }

        return Storage::response($path);
    }
}
```

Route

```
Route::get('media/{filename}', [\App\Http\Controllers\MediaController::class, 'show']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this code

routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
    Route::get('storage/storage_inner_folder_fullpath/{filename}', function ($filename) {
        return Image::make(storage_path() . '/storage_inner_folder_fullpath/' . $filename)->response();
    });
});
```

view file code

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/storage_inner_folder_fullpath/'.$filename) }}" />
```

Thanks

Comment: What is 'Image'? You didn't specify a definition.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Storage::disk('your_disk_name')->getDriver()->getAdapter()->applyPathPrefix('your_file_name');
```

Good Luck !

Comment: what is your_disk_name here

Comment: this will help you to know that https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/filesystem#the-public-disk

Answer (score 1):

Uploaded like this

```
$uploadedFile = $request->file('photo');
$photo = "my-prefix" . "_" . time() . "." . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension();
$photoPath = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('local')->putFileAs(
   "public/avatar",
   $uploadedFile,
   $photo
);
```

and then access like this

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/avatar/'.$filename) }}" />
```

Comment: `<img src="{{ asset('storage/avatar/img1.png') }}" />`  helped me to show the image

Answer (score 1):

**Create Route:**

```
Route::get('image/{filename}', 'HomeController@displayImage')->name('image.displayImage');
```

**Create Controller Method:**

```
public function displayImage($filename)

{

  

    $path = storage_public('images/' . $filename);

   

    if (!File::exists($path)) {

        abort(404);

    }

  

    $file = File::get($path);

    $type = File::mimeType($path);

  

    $response = Response::make($file, 200);

    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);

 

    return $response;

}

<img src="{{ route('image.displayImage',$article->image_name) }}" alt="" title="">
```

Answer (score 0):

can You please try this

```
$storage = Storage::get(['type_column_name']);
```

Comment: what is type_column_name

Comment: Your table column name where is store image path