# images wont display in view laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, image

i am storing images in storage folder and the url in database but when i want to show them in view they cant be found here is my code :

controller

```
  $filename = $request->file('agreement')->store('public/images');
    $client = Client::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
        'fax'=>$request->fax,
        'adrress1'=>$request->adrress1,
        'telephone1'=>$request->telephone1,
        'client_type'=>$request->client_type,
        'sellpercent'=>$request->sellpercent,
        'agreement'=>$filename,
    ]);
    return redirect('admin/client/'.$client->id);
```

view :

```
 <img src="{{url($client->agreement)}}" alt="some thing">
```

i tried moving file from storage to the main public folder manually but didnt work even when i put the url on the browser it gives a not found error after that i runned the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but yet again nothing happens and here is the url i am saving in the database

```
public/images/KMrCn80Cc9jlNqwLhcSjGM7JJ09lob6cnJGDuTel.jpeg
```

Comment: physically where does it store ?

Comment: check details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997652/laravel-retrieve-images-from-storage-to-view

Comment: Hello my dear friend rkj :) my problem is that i cant link the storage folder currectly so now i want to link the laravel\storage\app but it saves the storage\app\public when i run php artisan storage:link

Comment: i changed the storage path on file system config and runned the code again but yet again no hope

Comment: when you run `php artisan storage:link` then it create a symbolic link of `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` folder

Comment: yes let me show the problem cause i solved some part of it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176473/discussion-between-rkj-and-farshad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already created symbolic link of `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` folder using `php artisan storage:link`. So, now you only need to upload file using `public` disk like this

```
$filename = $request->file('agreement')->store('subfolder', 'public');
```

Here physical path of file is at `storage/app/public/subfolder` but as you have symbolic link of `storage/app/public` to  `public/storage`. Now you can access it publicly in view using `asset` like this

```
{{asset('storage/subfolder/' . $client->agreement)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

use asset:

```
 <img src="{{asset($client->agreement)}}" alt="some thing">
```

and store this path in database :

```
images/KMrCn80Cc9jlNqwLhcSjGM7JJ09lob6cnJGDuTel.jpeg
```

Comment: i must select public folder otherwise it wont become shared :(