# Laravel: Display image from public storage

Tags: laravel

I am saving an uploaded image like this:

```
$profile_picture = $request->file('profile_picture');
$user->profile_picture = $profile_picture->getClientOriginalName();
Storage::disk('public')->put( $user->profile_picture, $request->file('profile_picture') );
```

and then I am trying to display that image in HTML with:

```
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ asset('storage/'. Auth::user()->profile_picture) }}">
```

the image is being saved in storage/app/public, but the image is not showing in html, how do i go about this?

thank you

Comment: Please refer following url.
I think it can help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997652/laravel-retrieve-images-from-storage-to-view/50998571](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50997652/laravel-retrieve-images-from-storage-to-view/50998571)

Answer (score 0):

You may use `response` method on a Laravel filesystem

```php
return Storage::disk('public')->response($user->profile_picture);
```

N.B: In order to do that, you need a Laravel route. The above code should be located in a controller method